# Is it possible to resize an image when pasted into a rich text field

Tags: image, resize, xpages, paste

I am working on an xpages app, where the client wants to restrict the size of images that are pasted into the document.  I have restricted docs with the upload component, but not with a pasted image.

Has anyone done anything like this?

Thanks
walt

Comment: Pasted images end up as img tags with a data URL. So you could simply check the string length of it - gives you the Base64 length. Storage size depends on your compression settings

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, I haven't done this but there are a few ways you could go about it.

Excuse me if you already know this, but it is worth pointing out for anyone who comes across this question in the future, RichText as we knew it from Notes/Domino is not used XPages, it is all MIME. When I started Xpages I knew nothing about MIME so after understanding it all I have written a little summary on my blog to help anyone get used to the idea. If you are going to do anything with the InputRichText control and File Uploads etc. it is worth getting familiar with MIMEEntity's.
http://camerongregor.com/2016/04/21/webmail-ui-you-must-learn-about-mime/

There are 2 ways that images can make it into the 'rich text field', either *uploaded* using the 'Image' button on the editor toolbar, or alternatively in some web browsers, the image can be *pasted* from the clipboard. The 2 different methods will include the image in 2 different ways

**Uploaded**
If the image is *uploaded*, then the image becomes a multipart/related mime entity of some sort of image/jpeg, image/png etc., related to the text/html. Between the time that the image is uploaded, and the time that the Document is saved, the image file will be located on the server's disk, in the xpages persistence folder associated with the Document e.g.

```
xsppers_directory/application-id/session-id/document-id/someimage.png
```

**Pasted**
When pasted the image is not uploaded as a file to the server's persistence folder, but is instead included within the text/html as a data URI image (as Stephan mentioned in the comment above).

So, if you want a true solution you will need to address both avenues.

**Handling Pasted images**

I have shared a plugin on my blog which blocks pasted images, so this could be used to eliminate the 'paste' avenue altogether, and force users down the upload avenue.
http://camerongregor.com/2016/11/14/preventing-pasting-of-images-in-ckeditor/

Alternatively, if you are happy with having smaller pasted images, you could just 'restrict' it by modifying the plugin so that it checks the 'length' of the data URI (as Stephan suggested above) and allows the paste if the length is below your predetermined limit.

If even more alternatively, you could find some sort of client side javascript library that will resize images and do it there in the client before the paste.

Or another server-side option is you could process the contents of the 'text/html' MIMEEntity when saving, and find any img tag's that used Data URI's and strip it out, resize the image using some server side library such as ImageMagick and replace it.

**Handling Uploaded Images**

For uploaded images, an intense solution would be to extend the InputRichText control (similar to how the have demonstrated in the Mastering Xpages 2nd edition) and override the processAjaxRequest event so that it resizes the image during the process of uploading of the image and putting it in the persistence folder. You could resize it there and then using something like ImageMagick.

Or a less intense version would be to process the 'pending' attachments during a before save event. If you get the DominoRichTextItem from the DominoDocument, you should be able to iterate through the Attachments, checking their attachment state, there will be a state which means 'pending/about to upload' and for these ones you can process them while they are in the persistence folder, before they are finally attached to the document.

Finally if you don't want the xpages runtime / persistence directory to be involved, you could do it all after save, just using the backend NotesDocument and MimeEntity processing. Extract the Image MimeEntities to disk, process them with ImageMagick or similar, and then re-attach them.

Someone else may have a simpler solution that I haven't thought of but at least this gives you some idea of what may be involved.

Comment: Thanks for the info Cameron, I will give this a go.